# Why Mod4+D is not working for Firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, shortcuts

My keyboard shortcut for minimizing all opened windows is <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

It works fine for all windows (including Chromium) but for Firefox.

Why is this and what do I have to do so Firefox minimizes as well?

(versions: Ubuntu 11.04, Firefox 4.0)

Comment: Maybe an upgrade to Firefox 6 would help. You never know

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by accident. Control+Alt+Down Arrow